# Query and Display Data using Sheet Date Filter

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am trying to display data from the main sheet 'Team CRF' and display it on a second sheet but only show data that is 7 days between a date.

My query is:

```
=query("Team CRF"!$A$1:$E$1000, "select A, B, C, D, E where C > date '"&text(datevalue("1/1/2000"), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 1)
```

I get the error Formula parse error but can't understand why. Any help please?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Hello @AshyC, can you share a copy of your sheet which contains the desired result as well?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY('Team CRF'!A1:E, 
 "select A,B,C,D,E 
  where E = 'Appointment'
    and C > date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-7, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi,

I am now using: =QUERY('Team CRF'!$A$1:$E$996, "SELECT A, B, C, D, E WHERE E = 'Appointment'", 1)

This seems to work but doesn't utilise any date in the where clause. I need to add, WHERE C is 7 days AFTER todays date.

Comment: @AshyC fixed, try now

Comment: That works! Is it possible to change the TODAY'S date so that it will only show data where it's 7 or more days after any date shown in column C?

Comment: try: `=QUERY('Team CRF'!A1:E, 
 "select A,B,C,D,E 
  where E = 'Appointment'
    and C > date '"&TEXT(MIN('Team CRF'!C1:C)+7, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 1)`

Comment: That does bring back data but it appears to show dates that aren't 7 days plus. For example, two are showing that are 05/07/20 and 11/07/20. They should only show if it's the 12th or 18th.